# Docker with .net core 2.2: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I'm starting "playing" around with Docker and right away I'm stuck.
I followed [this very easy tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-docker-netcore-container), and everything goes as expected until I try to run the container.
When I do:

```
docker run --rm dotnetapp-dev
```

I receive this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"donet\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT [ "donet","out/Hello.dll" ]
```

The application itself (a stupid hello world) runs fine on the machine, but when I run into the container I get this error that I don't understand. Is like the donet exec is not found, but why? I installed properly the images as the example ask and the application builds fine.

Could you help me troubleshoot this?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: You have a typo in ENTRYPOINT

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev We caught that at the same time! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The error was very embarassing:

ENTRYPOINT [ "**donet**","out/Hello.dll" ]

Of course it was supposed to be

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","out/Hello.dll" ]
```